# Navigation map best practices

Tags: navigation

I am setting up a navigation map for a project I have started on. But I have one question.

Below is a simplified version of my navigation map.

[image]

You will see that at the end of every menu section I have a navigation item called help.

This help page is the same page for all of the sections the link appears in. So I would like to know what the best way to show that this is the same page for all sections would be.

Comment: Perhaps just one help, in the same way that you haven't got three separate logins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally have a separate list of global links on a navigation map, off to one side, rather than including them on each.

Answer (score 0):

If the sections 2.1 - 2.3 is part of a global navigation (?) containing no more than seven items I would use this layout:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpA7JY.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

- I'd put the common HELP ling in a different color, making it stand out, in the Global navigation.
- The items looks like Local navigation visible according to selections in the Global Navigation.

Comment: Hi Benny, this is pretty close to what I ended up settling on. However my local navigation would be determined by context. 

I was just wondering how to communicate this way of doing my navigation by using the navigation flow style I used in my question. However a received I satisfying answer below.